# Text font size adapting to space

Tags: python, algorithm, strings, mathematics, pygame

In order to practice my programming skills, I am trying to implement a Button class, to use in pygame. I know there are libraries like PGU, I do this to improve in programming.

I spent a bit of time creating **a function to find a good font size for the text inside the button**, depending on the length of the text and the dimensions of the button.

I came to this result, it's close enough to what I want. **However, I am looking for advice to improve this function** that looks wobbly:

```
def balanced_text_size_button(length, width, height):
    # sqrt(length) / length -> The higher the length is, the smaller this value become,
    # it decrease slower and slower as length increase (never reach 0).
    # pow(....., 1.6) -> The resulting value is multiplied,
    # the impact is more important on high value
    # (I don't think it makes much sense I found this empirically).
    length_factor = math.pow((math.sqrt(length) / length), 1.6)

    # If there is a lot of horizontal space for the text, the font will be big,
    # but if there is a lot of char to write it will be smaller.
    font_size = width * length_factor

    # This way the font is not too high
    if font_size > height:
        font_size = height * 0.9

    return int(font_size)
```

A preview of what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I'd simplify your maths:

$$
\text{font_size} = \text{width} * (\frac{\sqrt{\text{length}}}{\text{length}}) ^ {1.6}\\
(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x})^{1.6} = \frac{1}{x^{0.8}}\\
\text{font_size} = \frac{\text{width}}{\text{length}^{0.8}}
$$

After this we're left with your `if`, personally I think using `min` would be better here, `min(font_size, height * 0.9)`.
That way we know the maximum is \$\text{height} * 0.9\$ rather than \$\text{height}\$, and makes the `font_size` not jump.
This is up to you, but a jump in the font size is ugly in my opinion.

If we look at the affect of not using min and using min:

```
>>> balanced_text_size_button(1, 89, 100)
89
>>> balanced_text_size_button(1, 91, 100)
91
>>> balanced_text_size_button(1, 100, 100)
100
>>> balanced_text_size_button(1, 101, 100)
90
>>> balanced_text_size_button_min(1, 89, 100)
89
>>> balanced_text_size_button_min(1, 91, 100)
90
>>> balanced_text_size_button_min(1, 100, 100)
90
>>> balanced_text_size_button_min(1, 101, 100)
90
```

The above makes much more sense.
And so I'd change your function to:

```
def balanced_text_size_button(length, width, height):
    return int(min(width / math.pow(length, 0.8), height * 0.9))
```

And if you want to keep your description I'd use comments.
I wouldn't use a doc-string as the implementation details aren't needed by the end user.
I'd either use a heavy comment like you did:

```
def balanced_text_size_button(length, width, height):
    # Decide the font size by getting a desired with and height font size.
    # For text to not go out of the box, the smallest of the two wanted sizes is taken.
    # The width size is found by dividing the width by an exponential of the text.
    # An exponent is used to have a reduced affect on larger values.
    # The exponent 0.8 seems to give the best results.
    # The height is decided by picking a font size of 90% of it.
    return int(min(width / math.pow(length, 0.8), height * 0.9))
```

Or as the code is easy to understand, you can just say why you're using a magic variable.

```
def balanced_text_size_button(length, width, height):
    # The exponent 0.8 seems to give the best results.
    return int(min(width / math.pow(length, 0.8), height * 0.9))
```

Answer (score 2):

The function seems good and has helpful comments. One improvement I would suggest is to add a [docstring](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/documentation/#docstring-ref) which explains what the three arguments are and what the function returns (so that people can tell what it does without having to see the example picture).

I assume that `length` is the width of the text in pixels, this could be renamed to `text_length` to make it clear it isn't referring to the button itself.

Also, if the button has no text then `length` will be zero and so the first line will throw a `ZeroDivisionError`, so you might want to catch that and return some default value.

```
try:
    length_factor = math.pow((math.sqrt(length) / length), 1.6)
except ZeroDivisionError:
   length_factor = 1
```